# Set CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE property in CMake for every target

Tags: cmake, iwyu

I have multiple CmakeLists.txt in my project and I'd like to enable `iwyu`.

Adding

```
set_property(
  TARGETS MY-TARGET
  PROPERTY CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${iwyu_path}
)
```

would enable it for one target. I'd like to enable it for every target to avoid redundancy in another file.cmake I include in the CMakeLists.txt which already exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3 FATAL_ERROR)

find_program(IWYU_PATH NAMES include-what-you-use iwyu)
if(NOT IWYU_PATH)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the program include-what-you-use")
endif()
set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${IWYU_PATH})
set(CMAKE_C_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${IWYU_PATH})
```

The "documentation" can be found here: [CMAKE_<LANG>_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE.html)

Comment: It doesn't work. I think because it doesn't add the property to the target.

Comment: You need to do this before adding any target.

Comment: But your original code works for a single target? Or is/was it untested? Anyway, I updated the answer to make it more robust.

Comment: I had the cmake version, and it was installed, I ignore what it was but with your piece of code, it cannot fail for anyone. Thanks for your time

Comment: I would like to ue this tool. But in my project I use `gcc` as opposed `clang`. Will this still work. It hasn't been working so far.

Comment: @ilya1725 this works with GCC as well (I'm using cmake 3.19.4). You may need to do a clean build if you aren't seeing the IWYU warnings